# Filter Shortcodes when using get_page

Tags: filters, shortcode

I'm using the following line to show content from one page on another.

This line outputs the content's raw text of a shortcode:

```
<?php $id=3934; $post = get_page($id); $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); echo $content;  ?>
```

How can I add to or filter this snippet to allow the shortcodes from said page to fully display, rather than outputting raw [/tab] text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the shortcodes in the string variable `$content` you can use the Wordpress function `do_shortcode()` like this:

```
 echo do_shortcode($content);
```

See more in the Codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode